CORS error when using a biometric device API with React
I have an API that initiates scans for biometric data via a biometric device connected through USB and verifies the same data from the biometric device. This API has been installed on my Windows machine and has been integrated into a React app.
The API can be accessed on the local machine via http://localhost:1234/. I wrote a service in the React app for initiating a scan
   export const makeCaptureRequest = async() => {
    const instance = axios.create(
        {
            baseURL:"http://localhost:1234/",
            headers: {
                "Content-type":'application/json',
              },
        }
    )

    return await instance.post("?type=capture&temp1=ss&temp2=ss&temp3=ss")
}

and the service for verifying the biometric data captured via the same API
export const makeVerificationRequest = async(temp1, temp2, temp3) => {
    const instance = axios.create(
        {
            baseURL:"http://localhost:1234/",
            headers: {
                "Content-type":'application/json',
              },
        }
    )
    

    return await instance.post(`?type=verify&temp1=${temp1}&temp2=${temp2}&temp3=${temp3}`)
}

This is how the services are being used
const initiateAndVerifyFingerCapture = () => {
        if(biometricVerificationPassed){
            alert("Print has already been verified. Proceed with transaction")
            setDisableOrderButton(false)
            return
        }
            setOpenBiometricScanDialogue(true)
            setBiometricScanDialogueText("Place finger on device to begin scanning")
            makeCaptureRequest().then(
                response => {
                    if (response.data.status == "success") {
                        setScannedBiometricData(response.data.template)
                        setBiometricScanDialogueText("Scan Complete. Verifying... ")
                        verifyBiometricData()
                    } else if (response.data.status === "fail") {
                        alert("failed")
                        setOpenBiometricScanDialogue(false)
                    }

                }
            ).catch(
                error=>{
                    if(error){
                        alert("An error occurred, please try again")
                    }
                }
            )
    }

const verifyBiometricData = () => {
        subscriberBioData.find(async (item) => {
           
            makeVerificationRequest(item.temp1, item.temp2, item.temp3).then(
                response =>{
                    console.log(response)
                    if(response.data.score >=65){
                                         setBiometricScanDialogueText("Print has been verified. Please complete transaction")
                                         setBiometricVerificationPassed(true)
                                         setDisableOrderButton(false)
                                         return response.data.status =="success" && response.data.score >=65
                                     }else{
                                        console.log(response)
                                         setBiometricScanDialogueText("Verification failed, please try again")
                                        setBiometricVerificationFailed(true)
                                     }
                }
            )

        })
    }

Initiating a scan throws the following error in the console
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:1234/?type=capture&temp1=ss&temp2=ss&temp3=ss' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field baggage is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
The react app is hosted online on the Digital Ocean app platform. I have no access to the API code. The API came as an executable file with the biometric device.
How can I resolve the CORS error?  Using a proxy does not seem to work.

Request header field baggage does your API spec tell you to add a header key baggage? You can proxy your request through a server of your own that allows CORS from your domain, and your proxy server won't be subject to CORS restrictions at that point on your executable because it's a server-to-server request (no CORS involved).

You wrote: How can I resolve the CORS error? Can you not simply configure your server for CORS?

@AdamJenkins, yes it is running locally and I am able to curl it. The API is accessed successfully.

Curl doesn’t do Cors. What’s your backend

You could always put a proxy in front of it

Like I said (and Daniel said), if you can’t access the code to configure the CORS because it’s just an executable, then your only solution is to put a lightweight proxy in front of it - server to server isn’t subject to CORS - like this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy#setup-a-basic-stand-alone-proxy-server

The thing is @Nate - I don't see where the baggage header is getting added to your request, so I'm kind of curious. If you exclude that header key from this request (from wherever it's getting added) does that satisfy the CORS policy of the API executable?

Weird thing is I am not adding any baggage headers and removing the header key also throws same error. Curling works though

@DanielA.White, adding a proxy in the vite.config.js does not work. The local dev URL always prefixes the route.

    const corsProxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:1234/';

export const makeCaptureRequest = async () => {
    const instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: corsProxyUrl + apiUrl,
        headers: {
            "Content-type": 'application/json',
        },
    });

    return await instance.post("?type=capture&temp1=ss&temp2=ss&temp3=ss");
};

export const makeVerificationRequest = async (temp1, temp2, temp3) => {
    const instance = axios.create({
        baseURL: corsProxyUrl + apiUrl,
        headers: {
            "Content-type": 'application/json',
        },
    });

    return await instance.post(`?type=verify&temp1=${temp1}&temp2=${temp2}&temp3=${temp3}`);
};

